# Who starts updatedb process and why it uses 700+% CPU?

Tags: linux, cpu, centos, cron

I have a VPS running CentOS, and recently its CPU usage goes over 700% two times already. It always turns out to be a process named "updatedb" (as shown in the figure below).

[image: top]

After a quick search, I learned that it is an indexing cron job and I don't think I really need it. But when I try to disable it, I realize that I could not find the "mlocate.cron" in the "/etc/cron.daily" directory, which only has these files inside:

```
00webalizer  logrotate  makewhatis.cron  rpm  spamdyke
```

As for the "/etc/cron.weekly" directory, it has:

```
makewhatis.cron
```

So I don't understand how comes the updatedb process gets started two times in the recent two weeks, and each time it uses so much CPU.

At the time being, I have to kill the process manually from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from `man updatedb`: `updatedb` updates database for `mlocate` (also known as `locate`) and is run perodically by cron.

The cron job is defined in file `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate.cron`, if my memory serves me correctly (don't have a CentOS at hand right now).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However that's exactly the point that I don't understand, because I don't see "mlocate.cron" in the "/etc/cron.daily" directory.

Comment: As said, I'm not sure about the exact file name. But you could do `grep "updatedb" /etc/cron*/*`, that should reveal the real culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried grep "updatedb" /etc/cron*/*, but it returns nothing. So I really don't know who starts updatedb process, it seems not cron.